# Java Sending Email "Client Server"

Tags: java, eclipse

Trying to create a email client server through using JAVA and I have implemented the following but got stuck where to go next.. appreciate the help

I am trying to create a socket and set up the input and the output streams.  We Take user's request, call up the appropriate method (doSend or doRead), close the link and then ask if the user wants to do another read/send.

Email.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Email {
   private static InetAddress host;
   private static final int PORT = 21;
   private static String name;
   private static Scanner networkInput, userEntry;
   private static PrintWriter networkOutput;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      try {
         host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
      } catch (UnknownHostException uhEx) {
         System.out.println("Host ID not found!");
         System.exit(1);
      }
      userEntry = new Scanner(System.in);
      do {
         System.out.print("\nEnter name ('Mike' or 'Jack'): ");
         name = userEntry.nextLine();
      } while (!name.equals("Mike") && !name.equals("Jack"));
      talkToServer();
   }

   private static void talkToServer() throws IOException {
      String option, message, response;
      do {
         /*******************************************************
          * I am trying to cREATE A SOCKET and SET UP the INPUT and the OUTPUT
          * STREAMS. We Take USER'S REQUEST, CALL UP THE APPROPRIATE METHOD
          * (doSend or doRead), CLOSE THE LINK AND THEN ASK IF USER WANTS TO DO
          * ANOTHER READ/SEND.
          *******************************************************/
      } while (!option.equals("n"));
   }

   private static void doSend() {
      System.out.println("\nEnter 1-line message: ");
      String message = userEntry.nextLine();
      networkOutput.println(name);
      networkOutput.println("send");
      networkOutput.println(message);
   }

   private static void doRead() throws IOException {
      /*********************************
       * I am trying to full the read method
       *********************************/
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [JavaMail API tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html).